# Is there a way to remove the add-on from the Firefox store (AMO), so that I can re-submit it again from the preferred account?

Tags: firefox-addon

An add-on which I submitted from my personal Firefox account accidentally has to be submitted from my employer's Firefox account, What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

To fully delete an add-on requires contacting Mozilla to ask them to delete it manually. You can, however, "delete" the add-on from "Manage Status & Versions" (middle of the light-blue box on the left):

[image: Manage Status & Versions]

There is a big red button at the bottom of that page with "Delete Add-on":

[image]

The ID used will continue to be associated with the account which you submitted it from, specifically to prevent others from submitting new versions. That page says:

> Deleting your add-on will permanently delete all versions and files you have submitted for this add-on, listed or not. The add-on ID will continue to be linked to your account, so others won't be able to submit versions using the same ID.

If you don't contact Mozilla, you will need to abandon the ID the add-on is currently using and choose another one. This may be easy for a WebExtension based add-on, where the ID is often assigned by Mozilla once you submit the add-on for the first time. In which case, you will just need to re-submit.

You will probably not be able to re-use the add-on URL which you chose within the store. You will need to choose another one. What might be needed is to change the original one away from the URL which you picked. It's unclear to me if you will be able to re-use the add-on's URL. If you desire to keep the one you originally picked, you could try changing the original away from that URL prior to deleting the add-on.

I don't believe that add-on names must be unique, but that may be required. You could also change the name to something random prior to deleting the original. This is probably not required, but shouldn't hurt, and may help.

Comment: Got it @Makyen, Thanks for the help.